# How to check passed function name as paremter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, if-statement

I have a javascript function that accepts a function as a parameter. I want to determine the name of the function is passed. How is that possible with javascript?

Here is a code I have so far. $fnc == "SliderMoney" is working. It's always returning false.

```
function SliderCreate($id, $fnc) {
    $lbl = "#" + $id + "_lbl";
    $div = "#" + $id;
    $slider = $($div).slider({
    });

    if ($fnc == "SliderMoney") {
        UpdateDisplay($slider, $lbl, "$");
    } else {
        UpdateDisplay($slider, $lbl, "");
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Susan

Comment: How would you determine the name of the function if an anonymous function were passed as the parameter?

Comment: Why are you using `$`s everywhere?

Comment: I'm passing named functions so I'm not worried about anonymous functions.

Comment: I use $ as a personal preference.

Comment: `$` makes it very confusing. I use `$` as a prefix for jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't by default.

Perhaps you pass it an object or as a third parameter.

Comment: It sounds like it's easier to pass a boolean and then assign the function name inside the function.